# Converting a PHP array into a table in html

Tags: php, arrays

I am new to PHP and I have dabbled with basic arrays from the video tutorials. I need some help in converting a PHP multidimensional array into a HTML table. I have already wasted a bunch of time in trying to get in the format I wanted, and thought someone in this forum will have an easy and better answer for me. Thank you before hand.

Here is the PHP array format -

```
[   ["term" => 3, "val" => 0.7, "user" => ["name" => "user1"], "dept" => ["dep" => "dept1"]],
    ["term" => 3, "val" => 0.6, "user" => ["name" => "user1"], "dept" => ["dep" => "dept1"]],
    ["term" => 12, "val" => 0.5, "user" => ["name" => "user1"], "dept" => ["dep" => "dept1"]],
    ["term" => 3, "val" => 0.1, "user" => ["name" => "user2"], "dept" => ["dep" => "dept1"]],
    ["term" => 6, "val" => 0.2, "user" => ["name" => "user2"], "dept" => ["dep" => "dept1"]],
    ["term" => 9, "val" => 0.3, "user" => ["name" => "user2"], "dept" => ["dep" => "dept1"]],
    ["term" => 3, "val" => 0.4, "user" => ["name" => "user3"], "dept" => ["dep" => "dept1"]],
    ["term" => 6, "val" => 0.5, "user" => ["name" => "user3"], "dept" => ["dep" => "dept1"]],
    ["term" => 12, "val" => 0.6, "user" => ["name" => "user3"], "dept" => ["dep" => "dept1"]]
]
```

and here is the out put format I am looking for -
[image]

Basically, the table should list all the users along the rows and the columns should be the unique values of the 'terms' in the array. the values in the table should be field 'val'. In case there are multiple values for 'val', then it should be the maximum value of the 'val'.

I hope I was clear in my q. I look forward for your help.

Comment: Hello Welcome To Stack Overflow. Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) . Stackoverflow is a site where we help each other solve problems & no one is free enough to write particular functionalities for users. please add what you have already tried & what went wrong so that we can help you **Solve** the problems, not create functionalities for anyone. hope you understand.

Comment: My apologies for being clumsy in my post. As I am a newbie to php, my tries were basic.. Looped through the main array and made two arrays.. One for the user list, and one for the terms. While creating the html table, I looped through the term array and then the user array to get a 2x2 table. I failed flat in trying to get the values in the  table. In other words, I could not 'tranform' the main array into a format that would help me build the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest transforming your array first so that it is grouped by the user so that you can loop more sensibly. Essentially you would end up with:

```php
[
  [
    "user" => [
      "name" => "user1"
    ],
    "terms" => [
      "3" => 1,
      "6" => 0,
      "9" => 0,
      "12" => 0
    ]
  ],
  [
    "user" => [
      "name" => "user2"
    ]
    "terms" => [ ... ]
  ]
]
```

From there, it's easy to loop through each user and output the relevant data

```php
...
# in your HTML file
<?php foreach($users_data as $user_data){ ?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $user_data["user"]["name"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $user_data["terms"]["3"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $user_data["terms"]["6"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $user_data["terms"]["9"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $user_data["terms"]["12"]; ?></td>
  </tr>
<?php } ?>
...
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, Rylee.